# menu icon for labels in Qt designer

Tags: c++, qt

I want to set menu options for label in qt designer, like label name may be file and when clicked on label "file" it should display the SubMenu like save, close, exit.no action needs to be done. just sub_menu icon be selected and replace it with label file name.just help me with this and write a code its just 5 minutes of time, i am new to qt.

Comment: `just help me with this and write a code` Sorry, it doesn't work like that. Have you actually tried anything yourself? If you have, what didn't work? If you haven't, why?

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code writing service, It's a Q&A. Try it yourself first before asking.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is *not* a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

No code is required to do what you ask in designer.

In designer, you need a menu bar - there is one by default on a mainwindow (I don't think you can add one to a standard widget in designer).

Then just click where it says "Type Here" and type the name of the menu. You can then open the menu with the mouse and type a menu item name, again where it says "Type Here" to add a new item.

Once you have done that the menu item names can be changed or added the same way. 
There is a "+" symbol which will let you add a sub menu and its items in a similar way.